# JAXB Generated Classes from xsd file

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb, xjc

I have a xsd file that im generating into Classes with xjc / JAXB.

Now i want to use the  method `getOwne`r(function attached), and from this object i want to get the name of the owner..
The main problem that this method return an Object Class and not a Customer Class.
there is a way to achieve that?

**Notice:** this is a ref by attribute

Thanks!

Here is what i tried:

```
public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Statement.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        File xml = new File("src/Data.xml");
        Statement items =  (Statement)unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
        List<Order> orders = items.getOrders().getOrder();
        for(Order order : orders) {
            System.out.println(order.getOwner());
        }
}
```

Data.xml:

```
<statement>
  <customer number="E1" name="Tom" type="normal"/>
  <customer number="E2" name="Tomer" type="normal"/>
  <orders count="200">
    <!--1 or more repetitions:-->
    <order number="string" owner="E1" total="1000.00"/>
    <order number="string2" owner="E2" total="1020.00"/>
  </orders>
</statement>
```

Schema.xsd:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" ?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="http://www.java2s.com/statement"
           xmlns="http://www.java2s.com/statement">
    <xs:element name="statement">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="customer" />
                <xs:element ref="orders" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="customer">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence />
            <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:ID" />
            <xs:attribute name="name"   type="xs:string" />
            <xs:attribute name="type"   type="xs:string"
                          use="optional" default="normal" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="orders">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element ref="order" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="count" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:element name="order">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="number" type="xs:ID" />
            <xs:attribute name="owner"  type="xs:IDREF" />
            <xs:attribute name="total"  type="xs:decimal" />
        </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>

</xs:schema>
```

info in Order.java:

```
    @XmlAttribute(name = "owner")
    @XmlIDREF
    @XmlSchemaType(name = "IDREF")
    protected Object owner;
...

public Object getOwner() {
        return owner;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

by changing:

```
<xs:attribute name="owner"  type="xs:IDREF" />
```

to:

```
<xs:attribute name="owner"  type="xs:IDREF" >
                <xs:annotation>
                    <xs:appinfo>
                        <jaxb:property>
                            <jaxb:baseType name="Customer" />
                        </jaxb:property>
                    </xs:appinfo>
                </xs:annotation>
            </xs:attribute>
```

and

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" >
```

to:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
           jaxb:version="2.0" >
```

thanks for Markus for forwarding me to the right place.

for more info: [Customizing JAXB Bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/intro/custom.html)